# novnc error unrecognized service on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management, vnc, remote-access, openstack

I am trying to do the setup for openstack.

I installed novnc but when i try the command "service novnc restart" i get the error "novnc : unrecognized service".

What should I do ?

Comment: It seems that service novnc is not installed. `service novnc restart` command tries to exec script `/etc/init.d/novnc`. Verify `ls -l /etc/init.d/novnc`. Could you post which guide are you using in order to setup openstack e which apt command did you exec?

Comment: I am following this guide http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/. The command was "apt-get install novnc" and I do not have novnc in init.d

Comment: I searched novc in the documentation you indicated and found only this command: `nova get-vnc-console demo-instance1 novnc`. Could you post the specific page you found `service novnc restart`? Did you check system log `/var/log` in order to found any errors?

Comment: So, in 2014 the novnc package shipped without a sysV init script. In 2019 it has neither a sysV init nor a systemd unit file :(

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, my problem is getting this running from systemd (formerly I merely disliked systemd due to its poor documentation and bad architecture choices, but recently I've learned to really hate it).

In my research I came across [this question](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/need-assistance-writing-a-script-to-launch-at-startup-4175598084/page2.html) by rockymtngeek on www.linuxquestions.org. User norobro suggests:

```
[Unit]
Description=novnc service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/noVNC/utils/launch.sh --vnc 127.0.0.1:5901 --listen 80

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```